# How do i create a column 1-10 with a loop?

Tags: postgresql

This is an example but I want only a column with 1-10 values without other text columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefun_recordset(param_numcount integer)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$$
DECLARE
    result text := '';
    searchsql text := '';
    var_match record;
BEGIN
    searchsql := 'SELECT n || '' down'' As countdown, n as integer 
                FROM generate_series(' || CAST(param_numcount As text) || ', 1, -1) As n ';


    FOR var_match IN EXECUTE(searchsql) LOOP
        RETURN NEXT var_match;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;


SELECT r.n , r.countdown
FROM somefun_recordset(10) 
    As r(countdown text, n integer)
    ORDER BY r.n;
```

How do I create a loop in postgres?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I don't understand.

Comment: you mean values from 1 to 10 in an integer column?

Comment: yes I want an integer column from 1 to 10

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the loop or the dynamic SQL; looks like it could just be `Select n From generate_series(param_numcount, 1, -1) As n`. I'm also not clear what you're saying is wrong with your current function - is there an error, or just something wrong with the output?

Comment: My function generates a column with 1-10 and a column with down. I would like to have only a column with 1-10 without the second column with down.

Comment: So you just need to remove the second column from the `SELECT` list. Or just use `generate_series(10, 1, -1)` directly without the user-defined function.

Comment: I wish the complete function with parameter create function ...

Comment: something  else CREATE FUNCTION loop() AS $$
DECLARE 
results
BEGIN 
  FOR counter IN 1..6 BY 2 LOOP
    END LOOP;
return results
END; $$ language 'plpgsql'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current description, you seem to be over-complicating this.

As [described in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html), the `generate_series` function can generate a column of values from 10 to 1, like so:

```
SELECT generate_series(10, 1, -1) as n;
```

Or using it as a table alias rather than a column alias:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(10, 1, -1) as n;
```

If you wanted to wrap this in a custom function with only one parameter, it would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION countdown(param_numcount INT) RETURNS SETOF INT LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
    SELECT generate_series(param_numcount, 1, -1);
$$;
```

Then you would run it as:

```
SELECT countdown(10) as n;
```

Comment: I want a serie from 1 to 10